# setting width and height for background using css

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, image-size

I want to set background width and height of the image.

```
document.getElementById('outerModalPopupDiv').style.backgroundImage = "url('samandar_003.jpeg')";
document.getElementById('outerModalPopupDiv').style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
```

Now I want to set Image width and height. I know `background-size: 200px 50px;` set height and width, however I can't use the same. I have to set the width and height in above format.

If I use

```
document.getElementById('outerModalPopupDiv').style.background.size = "200px 500px";
```

it won't work. Image remain same as it is.

Any idea how can I make this working.

Comment: @rlemon : Not sure why, Netbeans was not showing that option :(

Comment: This is why I stopped using auto-complete in IDE's and editors. Makes you lazy and you tend to rely on the system and not yourself :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As seen [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp), the js syntax for CSS3's `background-size` is:

```
object.style.backgroundSize="60px 80px"
```

So, for the sake of copypasting comfort, try this:

```
document.getElementById('outerModalPopupDiv').style.backgroundSize = "200px 500px";
```

Comment: thanks... Netbeans was not showing me `backgroundSize` and hence I didn't find out. :(

Answer (score 1):

with css3 you can set the Background-size:

```
#outerModalPopupDiv {
    background-size: 200px 500px;
}
```

as you can see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_background-size)

alternatively if you want to set it with javascript you can create a css class and add the class to an element

javascript:

```
document.getElementById("outerModalPopupDiv").className += "resizeBg200x500";
```

css:

```
.resizeBg200x500 {
    background-size: 200px 500px;
}
```

or directly with javascript:

```
document.getElementById("outerModalPopupDiv").style.backgroundSize="200px 500px";
```

or another alternative with jQuery :)

```
$("#outerModalPopupDiv").css("background-size","200px 500px");
```

background-size is css3, but widely supported by many browsers as you can see [here](http://www.caniuse.com/#search=background-size)

Answer (score 0):

Personally  I'd make a class with the re sizing in and the add that dynamically using JS

http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/FFeEh/15/

```
document.getElementById('outerModalPopupDiv').style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";

var element = document.getElementById('outerModalPopupDiv');

element.className += element.className ? ' backgroundResize' : 'backgroundResize';​
```